# Persist express-session Authentication in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, session, redux

I'm trying to log into my API from my react e-commerce app and at first it does get logged in but the problem is that upon page refresh the state resets and in the client-side, I'm not logged in anymore, whereas if I try to log in again I'll get an error from my back-end saying I'm already logged in since in the back-end the credentials are saved in the session store.

I'm using express-session to save the user data in a store in the back-end and in the front-end, I'm accessing the login route with `axios` and `createAsyncThunk`. `axios` and `cors` both have withCredentials set to true in the front-end and back-end, respectively.

***Back-end:***

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    name: "pg.sessionId",
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1209600000, // 14 days
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: isProduction ? true : false,
      sameSite: isProduction ? "none" : "lax",
    },
    store: new pgSession({
      pool: db,
      createTableIfMissing: true,
    }),
  })
);
```

***Fron-end:***

```
// Login
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/loginUser",
  async ({ email, password }, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await axiosApiPrivate.post("/auth/login", {
        email,
        password,
      });
      return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
      return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
    }
  }
);

const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: {
    user: {},
    isLoggedIn: false,
    isLoading: false,
    hasError: false,
    errorMessage: {},
  },
  reducers: {
    updAuthState: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoggedIn = action.payload;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(loginUser.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.hasError = false;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = action.payload;
        state.isLoggedIn = true;
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.hasError = false;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.hasError = true;
        state.errorMessage = action.payload;
      });
  },
});
```

I tried setting the `localStorage` and getting its value with `useEffect` but the main problem is that when the cookie expires on the back-end, there's no way for the front-end to know it so it can clear the `localStorage`. The other issue is that when a user manually clears `localStorage` in their browser, the client-side gets logged out while still being logged in in the back-end so trying to log in again, results in an error saying "already logged in".

My own preference was to save the same cookie I get from the back-end in the Set-Cookie header when I log in, to the whole client-side cookie but no cookie gets set in the browser whatsoever.

I've spent hours on this issue and nowhere I look has a solid solution.

**Is there any way I can fix this frustrating issue or even any right way to handle express-session authentication in React?**

Comment: If the back-end sends a cookie that the browser does not store, it is perhaps blocked as a third-party cookie (check under Cookies in the network trace)?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen The cookie headers are only set in the login page after login is successful. After refresh and/or navigation, the cookie headers aren't there. (Even when they are set in the login page, they are only visible in the network trace. The specific session cookie is never in the Application Cookie section.)

Answer (score -1):

You have to put {credentials:true} after axios url

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please read the question carefully first. I did mention it in the question: "`axios` and `cors` both have withCredentials set to true in the front-end and back-end, respectively."

Comment: Use session store in db and make a get request like axios.get(url/user...) in app.js ...so everytime you refresh..it will be called  ...and in the backend when you make router.get(/user (req,res){ select * from profile where userid= req.session.id}.    So if there is a session is still valid it will provide your data