# Not able to set Cookies in browser in Express and React

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt, cors

I am trying to store JWt token in browser via cookies.

Post request on /login route in express is as follows:

```js
const accessToken = jwt.sign({ email }, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

console.log(accessToken)

res.cookie('jwt', accessToken, { httpOnly: true })
// console.log("Cokkie set is", cookie);
res.json({ message: 'Logged in successfully' });
```

Axios call for frontend is as follows:

```js
const res = await axios.post(
  `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/login`,
  {
    email: loginInputs.email,
    password: loginInputs.password,
  },
  {
    // credentials: 'include',
    withCredentials: true,
  }
)
```

Cors policy is set as follows:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL,
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  // exposedHeaders: \['Set-Cookie', 'Date', 'ETag'\]
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.options('\*', cors(corsOptions))
```

This code works perfectly in Postman and the cookies are being set but throws the following error in browser.Currently both client and server work on local host!

> login:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I tried everything mentioned in [Express Session Cookie Not Being Set when using React Axios POST Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251837/express-session-cookie-not-being-set-when-using-react-axios-post-request) but was not able to resolve the error.

Comment: What's the value of `FRONTEND_URL` environment variable?

Comment: FRONTEND_URL = 'http://localhost:3000'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `origin` configuration of `cors` middleware should be `http://localhost:3000`, add the `http` scheme. See [Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) doc, the valid `origin` syntaxes are:

```
Origin: null
Origin: <scheme>://<hostname>
Origin: <scheme>://<hostname>:<port>
```

A response that tells the browser to allow requesting code from the origin https://developer.mozilla.org to access a resource will include the following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://developer.mozilla.org
```

If the server sends the below response header to the browser.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost:3000
```

The client running on `http://localhost:3000` send a HTTP request to `http://localhost:8080/api/login`, the request header `Origin` will be:

```
Origin: http://localhost:3000
```

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` does not match `Origin`, the user agent will throw the CORS error.

The `Origin` request header is added to the HTTP request by the browser automatically.

> If a user agent needs to request resources included in a page, or fetched by scripts that it executes, then the `origin` of the page may be included in the request.

But your error message is: **The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'**

If you want to send the cookie from the client to the server use the `credentials: include` option for `fetch`. Then don't set the `origin` to wildcard `'*'` and set the `credentials: true` for `cors` middleware.

E.g.

`server.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  // set origin to a specific origin.
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  
  // or, set origin to true to reflect the request origin
  //origin: true,

  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
  res.cookie('jwt', '123', { httpOnly: true })
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Logged in successfully' });
})

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!')
})
```

`client/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.4.0/axios.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-uMtXmF28A2Ab/JJO2t/vYhlaa/3ahUOgj1Zf27M5rOo8/+fcTUVH0/E0ll68njmjrLqOBjXM3V9NiPFL5ywWPQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
      // use fetch
      fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/login', { method: 'POST', credentials: 'include' }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
        console.log(data)
      })

      // use axios
      axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/login', {
        withCredentials: true
      }).then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
      })
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Start the API server:

```bash
$ npx ts-node server.ts 
Example app listening on port 8080!
```

Start the web server:

```bash
$ npx http-server -p 3000 ./client/
Starting up http-server, serving ./client/
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:3000
  http://192.168.174.79:3000
```

Access the front end using URL: `http://localhost:3000`

Console logs:

```
{message: 'Logged in successfully'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised I had been using app.use(cors()) twice.
The backend server.js file had

```
app.use(cors(); // ......(1)

const corsOptions = {
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL,
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions)); // ......(2)
```

Since (1) was getting executed before (2) it was throwing error.
The code works perfectly fine now with code part in (2) only.

Note: Always make sure about the sequence of code snippets.Minor error but too hard to get through it sometimes!

Answer (score 0):

On the Server Side:

app.ts

```
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import express, { Application } from "express";
const app: Application = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "https://yourreactappurl",
  }),
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// For demonstration purpose

app.get("/cookie", (req:Request,res:Response)=> {
     let token = sign(new Date().toString(), process.env.JWT_SECRET);
     
     res.cookie("token", token, {
      maxAge: 7200,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
     });
     
     res.sendStatus(201);

})

app.post("/showCookie",(req:Request,res:Response)=> {
     if(!req.cookies.token){
         return res.sendStatus(403); // OR whatever you want
     }
     // Handle the token verification HERE
     res.sendStatus(200);
})
```

On Client Side ( ReactJS ):

package.json:

```
{
...
"proxy":"https://yourserverurl.com"
...
}
```

example requests in React code:

```
 const setCookie = await fetch("/cookie", {
        credentials: "include"
       });
 
 // Check that the cookie is set in browser console.

 const checkCookie = await fetch("/showCookie", {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({...yourData}),
       });

  // Response must be successfull.
```

This way, CORS policies are enabled in ExpressJS and cookies are saved on the React side, in every browsers ( Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc...). Not pretty simple ( for me at least xD ) but it's done.